# Django-Cross Model Query 3 Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am working on a practice project to create 3 separate pages that is Brand Page, Car Model Page and Car Model Variant detail page.

I am working on a project with three models car brands, car model, car model variants
When an user opens the Car model page they should see the list of variants in that car model

```py
class BrandName(models.Model):
    FullName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Slogan = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.FullName}"

class CarModel(models.Model):
    Brand = models.ForeignKey(BrandName, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
                              related_name="brands")
    ModelName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.ModelName}"

class CarModelVariant(models.Model):
    ModelVariantName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Brandname = models.ForeignKey(BrandName, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
                                  related_name="brands1")
    Model1 = models.ForeignKey(CarModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
                               related_name="model1")
    Doors = models.IntegerField
    SeatingCapacity = models.IntegerField

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.ModelVariantName}"
```

In `views.py` of the app:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . models import CarModelVariant, CarModel, BrandName
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

class CarModelVariantView(ListView):
    template_name = "carlist.html"
    model = CarModelVariant
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        list_model = super().get_queryset()
        data = list_model.filter(Model1=CarModel_instance)
        return data
```

In `urls.py` of the app

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("<slug:slug>", views.CarModelVariantView.as_view())
]
```

I am facing a blank page while loading `carlist.html` template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title%}
Car Brand Variants List
{% endblock%}
{% block content %}
<ul>
    {% for variant in data %}
    <li>{{ variant }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not see the list of elements because you are not using the naming correctly for the CarModelVariant model list.
By default, the variable that stores this list is **object_list**.

That is, if you want to iterate over the CarModelVariant list, you should use the following construction

```
{% for variant in object_list %}
    <li>{{ variant }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

if you want to use your variable for the list, you must specify the **context_object_name** attribute

```
class CarModelVariantView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'data'
```

**UPD**

Using attributes in classes with capital letters is considered bad form.